# Comparing double to an int

Tags: c++, comparison, type-safety

While reading the book *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++*, in Chapter 3 it sates that we can;t directly compare a double to an int. However, when I tested it out on Visual Studios, it was running fine with no errors? What does he mean by not being able to compare double to an int. Later, he explains that C++ provides an indirect way. Does he mean implicit conversion?

Comment: Slightly off-topic but you should be careful when comparing integer types to floating-point types. While a `double` is usually large enough to represent **exactly** any `int`, a `float` usually cannot do so.

Answer (score 6):

C++ has a sets of built-in operators defined in [[over.built]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.built). The behavior of the equality operator is defined in [[expr.eq]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq), in particular:

> <sup>[6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#6)</sup> If both operands are of arithmetic or enumeration type, the [usual arithmetic conversions](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv) are performed on both operands; each of the operators shall yield true if the specified relationship is true and false if it is false.

And [usual arithmetic conversions](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv) implies:

> <sup>[(1.3)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv#1.3)</sup> Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other shall be converted to double.

So if you compare an `int` with a `float`, a `double` or a `long double`, you get implicit conversions from `int` to `float`, `double` or `long double`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is an implicit conversion.

Consider the following program:

```
bool f()
{
    return 3 == 3.0;
}
```

If you [look at the AST](https://godbolt.org/g/syKhWf) generated by Clang then you see where the implicit conversion is done. Clang calls it an `ImplicitCastExpr`:

```
  `-BinaryOperator <col:12, col:17> 'bool' '=='
    |-ImplicitCastExpr <col:12> 'double' <IntegralToFloating>
    | `-IntegerLiteral <col:12> 'int' 3
    `-FloatingLiteral <col:17> 'double' 3.000000e+00
```

Comment: There is an implicit **conversion**. There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. (yes, Clang is using the term incorrectly)

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for the clarification. I'll update accordingly.