# What does this sentence mean in 'Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++'?

Tags: c++

I am reading *Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++* and encountered this sentence on page 79 about safe conversions:

> In §3.4, we saw that we couldn’t directly add chars or compare a
> double to an int.

I think we can compare like this, and it runs successfully

```
int a = 2;
double b = 3.5;
if (a > b)
{
    cout << "No";
}
else
{
    cout << "Yes";
}
```

Did I misunderstand the sentence?

Comment: What did it say in §3.4?

Comment: That sentence is not meant to be understood by itself. It is supposed to remind you of what you learned in §3.4, and it takes shortcuts with the terminology. If you think the sentence is false, it might be more accurate to conclude that you misunderstood §3.4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing double to an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50254409/comparing-double-to-an-int)

Comment: @Adola I am not surprised that it is not uncommon for people to not fully understand §3.4 but not realize it until they reach that sentence. That doesn't change the purpose of that sentence, does it?

Comment: It would improve the question to show the text of  §3.4 that is being referred to

Comment: @Adola It is *not* a liegitimate questioni unless the OP answers what I asked him and states what was in §3.4. Otherwise he is asking us to explain something he hasn't provided. We don't all have a copy of his book.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have a 64-bits platform, with 64 bits ints.

```
int i = 1152921504606846976;
double d = 1152921504606846976.1;

bool b = i < d;
```

Then, it's not so clear anymore. Your double might have less precision than ints, at some range. The comparison above is unsafe, even though  3 > 3.5 might not be.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, since the question is fundamentally about some text that isn't shown, but that statement is correct if you emphasize **directly**. When you add two `char` variables both get **promoted** to `int`, so you're not **directly** adding them, and the type of the result is not `char`. Similarly, comparing values of two different types requires promoting one of the values, so you aren't **directly** comparing them.

Whether or not such things are "safe" depends on what you mean by "safe".

Comment: Nowhere does OP talk about chars. they are talking about the second part of the statement, `int`s and `double`s

Comment: @Jeffrey --you cannot analyze that sentence by focusing only on one part that interests you. The key to that sentence is the word "directly" and what it means for the rest of the sentence.